# Cannot return nonempty string in mocking a function using Moq in ASP.NET MVC unit testing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I am developing a ASP.NET project. I am doing unit testing in my project. So I used built unit testing framework by Microsoft. I am using Moq to mock data in Unit Test. But I am having a problem a mocking a function that return string value using Moq. Then problem is it always returning empty even I mocked it to return nonempty string.

This is my controller and action to be tested:

```
public class RegionController : Controller
    {
        private IRegionRepo regionRepo;

        private IFileHelper fileHelper;

        private int RecordPerPage;

        public RegionController(IRegionRepo regionParam,IFileHelper fileParam,int recordPerPage = 0)
        {
            this.regionRepo = regionParam;
            this.RecordPerPage = (recordPerPage == 0) ? AppConfig.RecordPerPage : recordPerPage;
            this.fileHelper = fileParam;
        }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CreateRegionVM model)
    {
        if(model.ImageFile==null || model.ImageFile.ContentLength<1)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("ImagePath", "Image file is required");
        }

        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Region region = new Region
            {
                Name = model.Name,
                MmName = model.MmName,
                MmDescription = model.MmDescription,
                Description = model.Description,
                GeoLocation = model.GeoLocation
            };
            try
            {
                 region.ImagePath = fileHelper.UploadFile(model.ImageFile, "Uploads/Images");
            }
            catch
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(500);
            }

            if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(region.ImagePath))
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(500); // problem is here. always reach here even if I returned nonempty value from fileUpload function
            }

            //regionRepo.Create(region);


            return RedirectToAction("Create");
        }
        return View(model);
    }

}
```

I commented where problem exists in my code.

This is my testing code:

```
[TestMethod]
        public void Cannot_Create_If_Upload_Fail()
        {
            var file = new Mock<HttpPostedFileBase>();
            file.Setup(m => m.ContentLength).Returns(1);
            CreateRegionVM model = new CreateRegionVM();
            model.ImageFile = file.Object;
            Mock<IRegionRepo> regionRepoMock = new Mock<IRegionRepo>();
            regionRepoMock.Setup(m => m.Create(new Region())).Returns(new Region());
            Mock<IFileHelper> fileHelperMock = new Mock<IFileHelper>();

            //here I did not returned empty string. So test should be failed. 
            fileHelperMock.Setup(m => m.UploadFile(model.ImageFile, It.Is<string>(y=>y=="Directory"), null)).Returns(It.Is<string>(x=>x=="XXX"));

            RegionController controller = new RegionController(regionRepoMock.Object, fileHelperMock.Object, 3);
            var unknownView = controller.Create(model);
            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(unknownView, typeof(HttpStatusCodeResult), "View type is wrong");
            HttpStatusCodeResult view = unknownView as HttpStatusCodeResult;
            Assert.AreEqual(view.StatusCode, 500, "Status code is not 500 when upload error");
        }
```

As you can see, the above code should be failed because I did not return empty for file upload function. Besides, I also commented the create function to make sure the problem. I also tested in several ways to make sure the problem came from there. Why is that happening? Why is the mock method always returning empty string? By the above code test should be failed because I returned "XXX". How can I return nonempty value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use It.Is for return statements, you want to set it up to be what you actually want to return.

```
            fileHelperMock.Setup(m => m.UploadFile(model.ImageFile, It.Is<string>(y=>y=="Directory"), null)).Returns("XXX");
```

> I tried this way . fileHelperMock.Setup(m => m.UploadFile(model.ImageFile, It.Is(y => y == "Uploads/Images"), null)).Returns("something"); . not It.Is(x=>x=="XXX") in return. But "Uploads/Images" only work. When I passed other values, it does not work. Please why?

This is because you are hard coding "Directory" that value into the setup, try this:

```
fileHelperMock.Setup(m => m.UploadFile(model.ImageFile, It.IsAny<string>(), null)).Returns("XXX");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problema is the parameter for the directory:

```
fileHelperMock.Setup(m => m.UploadFile(model.ImageFile, It.Is<string>(y=>y=="Uploads/Images"), null)).Returns(It.Is<string>(x=>x=="XXX"));
```

Comment: I tried by changing parameter value. Still not working. The test is not failed even the return value is not empty.

Comment: I tried this way . fileHelperMock.Setup(m => m.UploadFile(model.ImageFile, It.Is<string>(y => y == "Uploads/Images"), null)).Returns("something"); . not It.Is<string>(x=>x=="XXX") in return. But "Uploads/Images" only work. When I passed other values, it does not work. Please why?